# R shiny server log error

Tags: r, shiny

Estoy realizando el debugging de una aplicación R-Shiny en el servidor y en el log recibo el siguiente error:

```
Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: cannot open file 'Rplots.pdf'
  80: <Anonymous>
```

Comment: Un ejemplo mínimo de lo que estás haciendo y particularmente del código que genera el warning es fundamental para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: No puedo compartir el código completo ya que forma parte de un proyecto Europeo. De todos modos el error que ofrece el log no se refiere a ningún código en concreto. Sino, obviamente, habría capturado esa parte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a otras [personas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6535927/236345) que han reportado problemas de su código interactuando con Rplots.pdf, es [posible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38605858/236345) que debas añadir

```
pdf(NULL)
```

en tu código para que no intente generar un plot en un archivo inexistente.

La otra opción puede ser que estás intentando abrir un device (por eso es tan importante que compartas el código que estás corriendo, porque nadie te dice que no te fijaste y es evidente. Sólo es ver qué comandos y opciones usas para ver si hay problemas ya conocidos). En este segundo caso, habría que usar `dev.cur()` para ver si hay un device esperando el plot o si está apuntando a null (y por ende, generando el error porque por defecto se lo va a enviar a Rplots.pdf)

Comment: No puedo compartir el código completo ya que forma parte de un proyecto Europeo. De todos modos el error que ofrece el log no se refiere a ningún código en concreto. Sino, obviamente, habría capturado esa parte

Comment: pdf (null) ha resuelto el error. Muchas gracias ! :)

Comment: @ElLoko36 se entiende. Muchos de los que pasamos por acá lidiamos con software que pertenece a nuestros jefes, a un proyecto, etc. Sin embargo, para hacernos entender y que nadie tenga que adivinar, es nuestra responsabilidad preguntar incluyendo un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).